# Using 'Enter' on keyboard to submit form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single text field and a button. The button calls a function called validate(). It currently only works if you click the button, and I'm trying to change it to take keyboard input using 'enter' on keyboard. I have written the following from tutorials, but it doesn't work - any pointers?

```
<input type="text" name="textField" onkeypress="handle(event)" onfocus="clearT()" />


 function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
    validate();
    }
```

Comment: looks correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the *onkey* function by using *getElementById onkeydown* instead of putting a onkeypress function on the *input* field itself.

```js
document.getElementById('my_id').onkeydown = function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 13){
     validate();
   }
};

function validate(){
alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my_id" name="textField" onfocus="clearT()" />
```

Comment: Thanks - I've actually got it to work without this, but as soon as you hit enter, the correct action happens (a message pops up) but then the field is cleared, and it disappears straight away! I don't know why that is happening....

Comment: What _dissapears_ straight away? Can you make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Sorry @Angel for being woolly- I've actually just worked that one out too. I have just figured out a bit of a usability flaw with it though. Is there anyway, I can lose focus on the text field after I've hit enter on the keyboard?

Comment: You can probably just use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp) Let me know if it worked @Pineapple

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
function handle(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode === 13)
 {
     validate();
    }
}
function validate()
{
 alert("hello");
}
</script>
<body>

<input type="text" name="textField" onkeypress="handle(event)" />
   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using is fine, but I assume you have a syntax error in `handle` function--missing `}` for if statement. And, it's always a good idea to check for both `keyCode` and `which`.

```js
function handle(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        e.target.blur(); // blur
        console.log('proceeding to validate()');
    }
}
function clearT(){
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textField" onkeypress="handle(event)" onfocus="clearT()" />
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. I had a syntax error as you pointed out! I just figured out a bit of a usability flaw with it though. Is there anyway, I can lose focus on the text field after I've hit enter on the keyboard?

Comment: @Pineapple, I have updated the fiddle. `.blur()` makes the element unfocused

Answer (score 0):

You could also move the validation to the form's onsubmit event. This approach removes the need to capture and interrogate keystrokes. As follows:

Wire up the form's onsubmit event to a javascript function:

**HTML**

```
<form id="world" name="world" onsubmit="validate(event)">
    <input type="text" name="textField" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('This is validate');
}
```

So when the HTML form has focus and you either click on Submit or press the Enter key the validate method gets called, and works with multiple forms on a page. Seems to me to be a cleaner solution as it uses the browsers default behaviours, instead of writing (rewriting?) keystoke management code.